# Extract char/numbers using Mid and Pos function

Tags: function, powerbuilder

I have a string with a value of "String_test|123456"

How can I extract the numbers and characters and put them to another variable
string2 = "String_test" and int = 123456 using Mid / Pos functions.

Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a PowerBuilder answer rather than the ones given...
You seem to have a string with a 'string' portion and a 'number' portion delimited by a pipe character '|'.  Assuming this is the normal format of the data you find the position of the pipe by:

```
li_pipepos = Pos(ls_string, '|')
```

Then the string portion is found thusly:

```
ls_string_portion = Mid(ls_string, 1, li_pipepos - 1)
```

The number portion is found:

```
ls_number_portion = Mid(ls_string, li_pipepos + 1 )
```

Then you convert the number portion into an integer (watch out since in PB an integer is not very large - i'd use a long instead) by:

```
ll_number = Long(ls_number_portion)
```

Now if your data isn't in a standardized format you will need to loop through all the characters to determine if they are a number or not and then append them to a string variable (one for numbers and another for characters) then finally convert the number string into a number.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `|` is the delimiter, it's easier to use [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) function to do this.

```
Sub Test()
    Const sampleStr As String = "String_test|123456"
    
    Dim splitArr() As String
    splitArr = Split(sampleStr, "|")
    
    Dim string2 As String
    string2 = splitArr(0)
    Debug.Print string2 'String_test
    
    Dim int2 As Long
    int2 = splitArr(1)
    Debug.Print int2 '123456
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify this user defined function to suit your needs.

```
Public Function ReturnIntegers(cell As Range) As String

   Dim stringholder As String
   stringholder = cell.value
   Dim pos As Integer
   pos = InStr(1, stringholder, "|", vbTextCompare)
   ReturnIntegers = Right(stringholder, (Len(stringholder) - pos))
   
End Function
```